# How to Create Hand-Drawn SVG Animation with a Mask

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I'm trying to create the below SVG animation with a mask. I have tried with CSS `stroke` properties, but I cannot get it the way I want.

[image]

Here is the W-shaped SVG I have created.

```css
path {
    stroke: black;
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2; /* Adjust the stroke width as desired */
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    animation: draw 4s linear forwards;
}

#path1 {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

#path2 {
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

#path3 {
    animation-delay: 8s;
}

#path4 {
    animation-delay: 12s;
}

@keyframes draw {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 677 689" style="enable-background:new 0 0 677 689;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M70.1,676L70.1,676c40,1.5,73.6-29.7,75.1-69.7l12.7-345.2c1.5-40-29.7-73.6-69.7-75.1h0c-40-1.5-73.6,29.7-75.1,69.7
    L0.4,600.9C-1.1,640.9,30.2,674.5,70.1,676z"/>
<path d="M274.2,682.2L274.2,682.2c38.9,9.2,78-14.9,87.1-53.9l97.8-415c9.2-38.9-14.9-78-53.9-87.1l0,0c-38.9-9.2-78,14.9-87.1,53.9
    l-97.8,415C211.1,634.1,235.2,673.1,274.2,682.2z"/>
<path d="M246,669.4l3.3,2.7c34.9,26,81.3,19.8,106.4-11.4L790.6,118c25-31.2,20-76.8-11.2-101.8l0,0c-31.2-25-76.8-20-101.9,11.2
    L242.6,570.1C217.6,601.3,214.8,644.4,246,669.4z"/>
<path d="M34.3,665.2l0.5,0.4c32.2,23.8,77.7,17.9,101.5-14.3L442.1,237c23.8-32.2,17-77.5-15.1-101.3l-0.5-0.4
    c-32.2-23.8-79.4-15.9-103.2,16.3L19.1,563.9C-4.7,596.1,2.1,641.4,34.3,665.2z"/>
</svg>
  </div>
```

**CODEPEN Link:
https://codepen.io/eshanrajapakshe/pen/KKbYQbG**

Please help me to create this animation or suggest me a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the svg you created. here is an alternate svg that should work with the codepen:

```html
<svg width="409" height="382" viewBox="0 0 409 382" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M45 109L58.5 291.5L197 81.5L205 337L363.5 45" stroke="black" stroke-width="90" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you tell me how you created this SVG? Did you use any tools?

Comment: I used figma as my tool of choice.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track animating the stroke, but in your case the thick "line" is drawn as an outline of the line. A better approach is to create one outline/line and then define a thicker stroke.

I imported all the paths you defined into [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) and made the new path following the old, then deleted the old.

```css
path {
  animation: draw 3s forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 788 676">
  <path d="M 72 248 L 60 616 L 373 191 L 277 616 L 728 60"
    stroke="black" stroke-width="120" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"
    stroke-linejoin="round" pathLength="100"/>
</svg>
```